# My Server memory and Inputs/outputs overloaded suddenly

Tags: magento2, memcached

My Server memory and Inputs/outputs overloaded suddenly
 my website link is https://buddsbuddy.com

to resolve this I have to log in to the server and kill PHP processes. tell me some solution for this

Comment: You need to check your server is compatible with M2 or not.  If yes then you should check your custom module which you are using in your project. In your custom module, you need to debug or find code that creates a query which is not in use every time. You can also trace query by show process SQL statement in MySQL.

Comment: Check: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

First, make sure you allocated **2GB of memory to PHP**; otherwise, your installation or upgrade might still run out of memory.

If you’ve already done that, create a swap file on your machine. A Linux machine uses swap space if it needs more memory resources and the RAM is full. The swap space is used for inactive pages in memory.

The following are suggestions only; other options might be available. Consult a network administrator or another knowledgeable resource before you continue. You must run the commands to create a swap file as a user with root privileges.

Reference : [Link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/out-of-memory.html)

Comment: I'm currently using Godaddy Linux cPanel server. I found one article about Memcached installation on the server. will it help?